# using a loop to rename columns in a lot of files

Tags: python, r, command-line

This may be a lot to ask but I am doing some processing of RNAseq files. I have nearly 1000 samples. I have used rsem to get a file that has the columns:  gene_id, transcript_id.s, length, effective length, expected_count, TPM, and FPKM. The row names are listed as 1, 2, 3, etc…. With the ensemble gene id in the first column. As you can imagine there are quite a bit of rows.  I am generating one of these files for each one of my samples. The files that are generated are named something like “01_123456_.genes.results”.  where the digits represent the sample ID.

In the end I would like to generate a single data frame that contains columns listing the gene_id, TPM, and FPKM for each sample. Its going to be a huge file. To keep track of everything in that master file I would need to change the column name for expected count,  TPM and FPKM to include the sample ID and then merge all of my files by gene_id. I am fairly a novice and can probably do this one at a time but am wondering if there is a quicker way to get this done. Perhaps some kind of loop using R, python, or command line. I am a little better at R for data wrangling  but can try to figure out how to do this with command line or python.
Right now I am using R and can do something like this for each file:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)

rsem_01_120405 <- read.table("01_123456_.genes.results", header = TRUE)

rsem_01_123456 <- rsem_01_123456 %>% rename(FPKM_01_123456 = FPKM, TPM_01_123456 = TPM, count_0123456 = expected_count)
```

From there I can merge each file by gene_id one by one. I do not need to keep the length, effective length, and transcript_id.s columns.

I think there might be some way to generate a list of all my files and use some kind of cut command to isolate the sample ID and call it  and then do something like

```
 “while read line……….….TPM_${sample}; done < list.text.”
```

I guess where I should start would be to just rename the columns in each file. I may be able to figure out how to merge them later.

If I somehow was able to explain what I am trying to do, any feed back/ help would be appreciated.

I use a loop or something else to like like:

```r
rsem_01_120405 <- read.table("01_123456_.genes.results", header = TRUE)

rsem_01_123456 <- rsem_01_123456 %>% rename(FPKM_01_123456 = FPKM, TPM_01_123456 = TPM, count_0123456 = expected_count)
```

for about 1000 files, instead of doing it for each file individually.

Ultimately need to merge each of these files into one master data frame.

Comment: Please do not abuse tags. Your code is in `r`, so that should be the tag you use.

Comment: Thanks. not trying to do that. just illustrating I can do it for each single file in R. and am asking if anyone can offer some advice or code in another language such as python, or command-line using a shell script, or can modify my R code I am happy to try and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the kind of problem that is easy to solve using the  data manipulation functions in the tidyverse packages. Since you don't include example data, I made a simple example dataset to work with

First, we load in the files and store them in one big list:

```
library(tidyverse)

# get list of files
files <- list.files(pattern='*results')
# get sample ID from filename
names(files) <- gsub('_\\..*$', '', files)

# Read in files and remove unwanted data.
# Then, store dataframes in list, name list items with sample ID
data_list <- lapply(files, function(f) {
    read.table(f, header=T) %>%
        select('gene_id', 'expected_count', 'TPM', 'FPKM')
}) %>%
    setNames(names(files))
```

Now I'll make a simple example dataset:

```
lst <- list('a'=data.frame('gene_id'=c(1,2,3), 'TPM'=c(100,200,300), 'FPKM'=c(900,499,399)),
           'b'=data.frame('gene_id'=c(1,2,3,4), 'TPM'=c(400,500,6,700), 'FPKM'=c(2100,599,9999,32)))

$a
  gene_id TPM FPKM
1       1 100  900
2       2 200  499
3       3 300  399

$b
  gene_id TPM FPKM
1       1 400 2100
2       2 500  599
3       3   6 9999
4       4 700   32
```

Now, we can bind these data.frames together into one and use the `pivot_*` functions to spread it into wide form where `gene_id` uniquely identifies rows and the other columns are the concatination of stat and sample_id:

```
 lst %>%
    bind_rows(.id='sample_id') %>%
    pivot_longer(-c('sample_id', 'gene_id')) %>%
    pivot_wider(id_cols='gene_id', names_from=c('name', 'sample_id'))

  gene_id TPM_a FPKM_a TPM_b FPKM_b
    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1       1   100    900   400   2100
2       2   200    499   500    599
3       3   300    399     6   9999
4       4    NA     NA   700     32
```

Comment: OK. this is good. I see what you are doing here and the end result is along the lines of what I want to do. and yes I should have included examples of the data. I will do this in the future. I appreciate the work you put into explaining this.  I am still having a bit of trouble though. I will try and explain a bit better. I will edit my question and include example df(s)

Comment: Ok. I cannot figure out to do a code block or example table here. but where I am having trouble is that your example df (lst) has multiple data sets in it, where as I am working with a single data set for each file. Maybe I can start smaller and try and figure out how to create a single data frame from the original data set. where I only include the gene_id column and the TPM column. I think I can do that by subsetting but still need to rename the TPM column to include the sample ID. I really hoe this makes sense. again, thanks for your time.

Comment: If I understand your data, what you have is a directory of files, 1 file per sample. Each file contains the gene expression data for 1 sample, and your goal is to get all that data into a single data.frame, instead of multiple files. This is what I show above: In this example, there are 2 files: one with the results for sample "a" and one with the results for sample "b". We loop through each of these files and load each file's data into a separate dataframe, each of which are stored in a list `lst`. Does that make sense? Am I understanding your data correctly?

Answer (score 1):

To approach this kind of problems it is often helpful to identify and resolve each step individually.

1. Write and test a function to read a single file and rename/add/modifiy columns

```
rf <- function(fn) {
  read.table(fn, header = TRUE) |>
    mutate(sample_ID = fn) # add more steps if necessary
}
# check if the function does what is expected by calling it with a single file
rf("01_123456_.genes.results")
```

2. Call the function for every file name

```
list_of_files <- list.files(pattern="*.genes.results")
full_data <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(list_of_files, rf))
```

Note that you cannot combine `data.frame`s with different column names. It is however simple to store the sample ID as an additional column in your `data.frame`.

The second part is not as obvious to understand. First we generate a list of all files (check out the documentation for the `list.files` function if you need to specify a directory). Then we call the previously defined `rf` function for each of the filenames (that's the `lapply` part) which gives us a list of `data.frame` that we bind together by calling `rbind.data.frame` with our list of individual `data.frame`s as argument (`do.call` calls the function given as first argument with the arguments to said function given as list).

Answer (score 0):

See if the following works. It renames the columns of all files in parallel, since you have so many. The final result, `df_new`, are the data.frames already `rbind`ed.

```
library(parallelly)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

rename_fun <- function(file, new_names = c("FPKM", "TPM", "expected_count")) {
  data <- read.table(file, header = TRUE)
  i1 <- grep(new_names[1], names(data))
  i2 <- grep(new_names[2], names(data))
  i3 <- grep("count", names(data))
  old_names <- names(data)[c(i1, i2, i3)]
  old_names <- setNames(old_names, new_names)
  data %>% rename(all_of(old_names))
}

ncores <- availableCores(omit = 2L)
cl <- makeCluster(ncores)
registerDoParallel(cl = cl)

filenames_vec <- list.files(
  path = "~/Temp", 
  pattern = "\\.genes\\.results$", 
  full.names = TRUE
)

df_new <- foreach(f = filenames_vec, .combine = "rbind", .packages = "dplyr") %dopar% {
  rename_fun(f)
}

stopCluster(cl)

head(df_new)
str(df_new)
```

Comment: This one is a bit intense. let me see if I can get it to work and figure out where I need to plug in stuff to read my files. Maybe I can start small by just renaming columns in each and not binding or merging the files. let me see if I can use this just to generate a single file for each with the gene_id column and the TPM column renamed to include the sample_id.